# DOMXpath/DOMDocument - How to parse HTML dom elements not only with simple text

Tags: html, dom, domdocument, domxpath

Here is my code:

```
$url = "https://www.leaseweb.com/dedicated-servers/single-processor";

libxml_use_internal_errors(true); 
$doc = new DOMDocument();

$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$n = $xpath->query('//td[@data-column-name="Model"]');
$r = $xpath->query('//td[@data-column-name="RAM"]');
$l = $xpath->query('//td[@data-column-name="Location"]');
$item = 0;
$i = 0;
foreach ($n as $entry) {
    $Name = $entry->nodeValue;
    $RAM  = $r->item($item)->nodeValue;
    $Location  = $l->item($item)->nodeValue;
    $i++;
    ?>
     <tr> <td><?PHP echo $i;?></td> <td><?PHP echo $Name;?></td> <td> <?PHP echo $RAM;?> </td> <td class="hidden-xs"><?PHP echo $Location;?> </td> <td><span class="label label-success">Configure</span></td> </tr>
    <?PHP
    $item++;
}
```

This code is giving me results only like text:
The selected `td` element with `data-column-name="Location"` for example holds `<span id="inside_element">Holded text</span>` and instead of getting it with the `span` i receive only simple text like this: `Holded text`.

How can i fetch and the HTML elements inside specific dom html element ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you need to grab raw HTML fragment from specific node you must invoke [DOMNode::C14N()](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.c14n.php).
This method canonicalize nodes to a raw HTML string. Let's take a look on this example:

```
<?php 
$html = '<html>
<head>  
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div>
            <span>text span</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>';

$dom = DOMDocument::loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//div[@class="container"]/div');


print $nodes->item(0)->C14N();
```

As I want to get HTML content under `div.container > div` the output will be::

```
<div>
    <span>text span</span>
</div>
```

## Alternative method

There is a less conventional method to achieve the same result. That is, saving the HTML of a specifc HTML node, like this:

```
$node = $nodes->item(0);

print $node->ownerDocument->saveHTML($node); // equivalent: $nodes->C14N();
```

So on your specific case, it's something like this:

```
<?php 
$url = "https://www.leaseweb.com/dedicated-servers/single-processor";
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$l = $xpath->query('//td[@data-column-name="Location"]/div');

var_dump($l->item(0)->C14N()); 
# Or $l->item(0)->ownerDocument->saveHTML($l->item(0));
```

Comment: Please edit your answer using the `$url = "https://www.leaseweb.com/dedicated-servers/single-processor";` bacause it seems i can not understand you and make it work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @TonyStark Don't you cannot read PHP docs? The above method that I've explained is easy to adapt. Work it!

Comment: It seems to be not working with my question example where i am using url.

Comment: @TonyStark Because there's no any <span id="inside_element"> under data-column-name="Location"

Comment: Forgive me about that, there is `<div class="gray"></div>` for data-column-name="RAM" Thanks!

Comment: @TonyStark So you should: $l = $xpath->query('//td[@data-column-name="Location"]/div'); echo $l->item(0)->C14N(); I've edited my answer.

Comment: I see your edited answer, but i do not understand one thing. From where comes this `$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);` here i see `$dom` but where `$dom` is declared ?

Comment: @TonyStark Oh, my bad... But just swap by $doc instead (in other words, the instance of DomDocument). It's obvious.

Comment: Yes i have done that and everything works like i wanted to be. Thank you so much!